# Google Charts Horizontal Axis wrong date

Tags: date, google-visualization

[image: window.google.visualization.DataView]

In the pic above, the horizontal axis is a day ahead of the actual values. Very new to google charts and cant figure out what the issue could be. I have verified the data being passed to the chart is the 14th, 15th, and 16th.

google.visualization.ComboChart

Comment: Can you share the code snippet that you're working with?

Comment: Thanks for your reply DogEatDog, but I found the issue and have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer to this. The problem was javascript subtracting a day from the date range.

Here is how I was initially setting the date:

```
var dt = new Date($(child).text());
dt.setDate(dt.getDate());
addData.push(dt);
```

Solution

```
var year = parseInt($(child).text().split("-")[0]);
var month = parseInt($(child).text().split("-")[1])-1;
var day = parseInt($(child).text().split("-")[2]);
var dt = new Date(year, month, day);
addData.push(dt);
```

Comment: If this is the correct answer, please select it as the correct answer.